# No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_DIFF.... error on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the timestamp difference between two date fields in my table. I know both dates are on TIMESTAMP format, but when I tried using TIMESTAMP_DIFF function I get an error saying "No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_DIFF for argument types: STRING, STRING, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART) at [27:8]"

I also tried formatting them again in the query(as done on the example for FIRST_VALUE(): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime_diff , and then it showed the same error but for FORMAT_TIMESTAMP.

[image]

Any ideas what I could do to fix this or to get the time difference between two fields for each row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', prev_time), PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', event_datetime), MINUTE)
FROM `project.dataset.messages`
```

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider voting up the answer - it is equally important on SO